# Differences in OpenCV cvtColor BGR2HSV conversion with float32 image

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I am working with OpenCV to convert an image from RGB to HSV. Ultimately, I have a Matlab routine that I am trying to implement in Python, so I am double checking my conversions against the values obtained in Matlab. I've got some questions about the conversion of RGB to HSV using OpenCV. For example, take these two different ways of converting the image.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Using Matlab, the max value of the hue matrix is found as:

```
>> I = imread(img_path);
>> I_hsv = rgb2hsv(I);
>> max(max(I_hsv(:,:,1)))

ans =

    0.9979
```

Using the HSV matrices obtained using OpenCV:

```
In [1]: cv2.minMaxLoc(hsv1[:,:,0]/180.)

Out[1]: (0.0, 0.9944444444444445, (72, 0), (1013, 399))

In [2]: cv2.minMaxLoc(hsv2[:,:,0]/360.)

Out[2]: (0.0, 0.9979166388511658, (72, 0), (456, 768))
```

So I have two questions.

1) Why when I convert to float32 does the hue matrix have a maximum value of 360, instead of 180?

2) Why does the conversion to float32 make the value of the hue matrix closer to that computed using Matlab?

Comment: 2) It is a precision issue when doing the computations. 1) See https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv when computing HSV, H is in range 0 to 360. It is only divided by 2 so that the max is 180 for 8-bit values so that it fits in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: OK, so when I convert to float32 (from numpy.uint8), the hue range will automatically be changed to have a max of 360? Which of the methods of conversion are more accurate?

Comment: If you convert 8-bit to HSV and then convert to float, it will still be max of 180. You should convert to float, then convert to HSV.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean; that by first converting the image to float32, the resulting hue values will range from 0-360. You're saying that the method used to generate hsv2 is more accurate, correct?

Comment: Yes, I would think so and also be in range H 0 to 1 corresponding to 0 to 360

Comment: *"You're saying that the method used to generate hsv2 is more accurate, correct?"* It's the same computation. But the result is rounded to the nearest even angle (because of the division by 2 and it being an integer result). The discretization makes the result less accurate.

Answer (score 1):

@fmw42 is correct in that the opencv spec calls for H to be divided by 2 when the output type is uint8 providing a range of H from 0 to 180.  The range of H will be 0 to 360 if the output type is float32.

This stuffing of values is not ideal for consistency or comparing results when data may be in different formats, but at least it is documented.

From [color_conversions v4.7.0:](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv)

> RGB ↔ HSV
>
> ...
>
> On output 0≤V≤1, 0≤S≤1, 0≤H≤360 .
>
> The values are then converted to the destination data type:
>
> 8-bit images: V←255V,S←255S,H←H/2(to fit to 0 to 255)
>
> 16-bit images: (currently not supported) V<−65535V,S<−65535S,H<−H
>
> 32-bit images: H, S, and V are left as is